# Error on assigning a value to a Rectangle in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, rect

I was trying to make a function that drew a rectangular map onto the screen. This function is:

```
def parseMap(mapIndex):
    tileRect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 32, 32)
    for x in maps.mapData[mapIndex]:
    tileRect.x = x*16
    for y in x:
        tileRect.y = y*16
        c.blit(maps.grass, tileRect)
        if maps.mapData[mapIndex][x][y] == 1: c.blit(maps.tallGrass, tileRect)
```

Though, I was getting an error,

```
TypeError: invalid rect assignment
```

on the line:

```
tileRect.x = x*16
```

and I can't see anything wrong with the code. Thanks!

Comment: What's `x`? (what's in `maps.mapData[...]`?) On the next line you iterate through it (`for y in x:`), is it a list maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you have an error and your indentation is correct? I ran the same code and have no error.

Comment: @Seth maps.mapData is a 3-dimensional list, where [mapIndex] is the map, then it has the coordinates [x] and [y].

Comment: @Seth Oh my god, I can't believe I didn't realize that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is a list, then `x * 16` does list repetition, not multiplication.

i.e., you're getting something like

```
tileRect.x = [1, 1, 1, 1, ...]
```

Comment: moved comment to answer.